# Curl C# Construction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, curl

I have a GET url as follows

```
curl -u rzp_test_26ccbdbfe0e84b80f4ab23e6:69b2e24411e384f91213f22a \ 
https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/?count=2&skip=1&from=1400826740"
```

where rzp_test_26ccbdbfe0e84b80f4ab23e6 is API key and 69b2e24411e384f91213f22a is secret key i need to ping this url

in C# using HttpClient how should I Do this

```
using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient()) 
{
    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("rzp_test_26ccbdbfe0e84b80f4ab2‌​3e6", "69b2e24411e384f91213f22a"); 
    string url = "api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/";; 
    var response = hc.GetAsync(url); 
    var content_res = response.Result;
}
```

i am getting error as unauthorised

Thanks in Advance

Comment: using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
            {
                hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("rzp_test_26ccbdbfe0e84b80f4ab23e6", "69b2e24411e384f91213f22a");
                string url = "https://api.razorpay.com/v1/payments/";
                var response = hc.GetAsync(url);
                var content_res = response.Result;
            } i am getting error as unauthorised

Comment: Code in comments is almost unreadable.  It's preferred that you instead edit the question with the code.  I've done this for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cURL `-u` option sets the HTTP `Authorization` header to `Basic` and base64 encodes the value.

The code you need to use to set that header with the `HttpClient` according to your cURL command is:

```
hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic", 
    Convert.ToBase64String(
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "rzp_test_26ccbdbfe0e84b80f4ab23e6", "69b2e24411e384f91213f22a")
        )
    )
);
```